# Buffered and Reactive aggregation service

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-webflux, reactive-programming

I am working on a buffered aggregation service.
The aggregation service calls 3 different services (let's call then s1, s2 and s3) and returns aggregated result.
The aggregation service is itself called by client passing parameters that will be used to call s1, s2 and s3.
To avoid overwhelming s1, s2 and s3 with calls , we buffer the calls.
We accumulate the parameters for each service till we reach 5 params at least. Once we accumulate 5 params for a service we emit the call and get the result. The aggregated result will be returned only if the 3 services were called and returned a result.

Here is my reactive implementation :

```
@Service
public class MyAggregationService {

    @Autowired
    private PricingClient pricingClient;
    @Autowired
    private TrackClient trackClient;
    @Autowired
    private ShipmentsClient shipmentsClient;

    private final Many<List<String>> pricingSink;
    private final Many<List<String>> trackSink;
    private final Many<List<String>> shipmentsSink;
    Flux<Mono<Map<String, Optional<Float>>>> pricingMonoFlux;
    Flux<Mono<Map<String, Optional<String>>>> trackMonoFlux;
    Flux<Mono<Map<String, Optional<List<String>>>>> shipmentsMonoFlux;

    public MyAggregationService() {
        pricingSink = Sinks.many().multicast().onBackpressureBuffer();
        trackSink = Sinks.many().multicast().onBackpressureBuffer();
        shipmentsSink = Sinks.many().multicast().onBackpressureBuffer();

    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void setUp() {
        pricingMonoFlux = pricingSink.asFlux().log().flatMapIterable(Function.identity())
                .bufferTimeout(5, Duration.of(5, SECONDS))
                .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                .map(pricingClient::getPricing)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());

        trackMonoFlux = trackSink.asFlux().log().flatMapIterable(Function.identity())
                .bufferTimeout(5, Duration.of(5, SECONDS))
                .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                .map(trackClient::getTrack)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());

        shipmentsMonoFlux = shipmentsSink.asFlux().log().flatMapIterable(Function.identity())
                .bufferTimeout(5, Duration.of(5, SECONDS))
                .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                .map(shipmentsClient::getShipment)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
    }

    public Mono<AggregateResult> aggregate(Optional<List<String>> pricing,
                                           Optional<List<String>> track,
                                           Optional<List<String>> shipments) {


        pricing.filter(not(List::isEmpty)).ifPresent(l -> pricingSink.tryEmitNext(l));
        track.filter(not(List::isEmpty)).ifPresent(l -> trackSink.tryEmitNext(l));
        shipments.filter(not(List::isEmpty)).ifPresent(l -> shipmentsSink.tryEmitNext(l));

        pricingMonoFlux.subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
        shipmentsMonoFlux.subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
        trackMonoFlux.subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());


        var zipped = Flux.zip(pricingMonoFlux, trackMonoFlux, shipmentsMonoFlux);
        Mono<AggregateResult> next = zipped
                .flatMap(t -> getZip(t))
                .map(t -> new AggregateResult(t.getT1(), t.getT2(), t.getT3()))
                .next();
        return next;
    }

    private static Mono<Tuple3<Map<String, Optional<Float>>, Map<String, Optional<String>>, Map<String, Optional<List<String>>>>> getZip(Tuple3<Mono<Map<String, Optional<Float>>>, Mono<Map<String, Optional<String>>>, Mono<Map<String, Optional<List<String>>>>> t) {
        return Mono.zip(t.getT1(), t.getT2(), t.getT3());
    }
```

}

I used 3 sinks (one for the params of each service) and used the buffer function.
The issue here is the sinks get canceled after one call.

What can be the solution here?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the Flips are subscribing to the `Sinks.Many` Flux inside the aggregate method which is not the expected behavior since you are using `subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())` again inside aggregate method this may be causing your `Flux` to complete and cancel your Sinks. `subscribeOn` call should ideally be at the initialization phase only and not during each call to the aggregate method. you can try below one ,

```
@Service
public class MyAggregationService {

    @Autowired
    private PricingClient pricingClient;
    @Autowired
    private TrackClient trackClient;
    @Autowired
    private ShipmentsClient shipmentsClient;

    private final Sinks.Many<List<String>> pricingSink = Sinks.many().replay().all();
    private final Sinks.Many<List<String>> trackSink = Sinks.many().replay().all();
    private final Sinks.Many<List<String>> shipmentsSink = Sinks.many().replay().all();

    private final Flux<List<Mono<Map<String, Optional<Float>>>>> pricingFlux;
    private final Flux<List<Mono<Map<String, Optional<String>>>>> trackFlux;
    private final Flux<List<Mono<Map<String, Optional<List<String>>>>> shipmentsFlux;

    public MyAggregationService() {
        pricingFlux = pricingSink.asFlux()
                .flatMapIterable(Function.identity())
                .buffer(5)
                .map(pricingList -> pricingClient.getPricing(pricingList));

        trackFlux = trackSink.asFlux()
                .flatMapIterable(Function.identity())
                .buffer(5)
                .map(trackList -> trackClient.getTrack(trackList));

        shipmentsFlux = shipmentsSink.asFlux()
                .flatMapIterable(Function.identity())
                .buffer(5)
                .map(shipmentsList -> shipmentsClient.getShipment(shipmentsList));
    }

    public Flux<AggregateResult> aggregate(Optional<List<String>> pricing,
                                           Optional<List<String>> track,
                                           Optional<List<String>> shipments) {

        pricing.filter(not(List::isEmpty)).ifPresent(l -> pricingSink.tryEmitNext(l));
        track.filter(not(List::isEmpty)).ifPresent(l -> trackSink.tryEmitNext(l));
        shipments.filter(not(List::isEmpty)).ifPresent(l -> shipmentsSink.tryEmitNext(l));

        return Flux.zip(pricingFlux, trackFlux, shipmentsFlux)
                .flatMap(tuple -> Mono.zip(tuple.getT1(), tuple.getT2(), tuple.getT3())
                        .map(t -> new AggregateResult(t.getT1(), t.getT2(), t.getT3())));
    }
}
```

`setUp` method directly subscribes to the Sinks. Many Flux and buffers incoming elements into a list of size 5 before making a call to each service. The aggregate method will only push the new parameters into each Sink and will not subscribe to them again. Also,`buffer(5)` method used here will only emit items when it accumulates 5 items in the buffer. If system can tolerate some delay, you can consider using the `bufferTimeout(5, Duration.of(5, SECONDS))` to emit items even if they do not reach 5 items in the buffer within the provided duration. `Mono.zip` in aggregate will combine the most recent published elements from each Mono. it might not behave as you expect if calls to these methods do not always complete in the same order.

This will fix the issue with the cancellation of the sinks after one call, since the sinks are now subscribed only once and the subscription is not cancelled after the first call.

Comment: thanks, but I. don't get this part  Mono.zip(
                pricingClient.getPricing(),
                trackClient.getTrack(),
                shipmentsClient.getShipment()
        ).  these methods need list as params

Comment: Yes you are right,Revised ! these service methods would need parameters. If you need to get a result immediately after buffering enough elements this approach becomes a bit more complicated.

Assuming the service calls are asynchronous and return Mono or Flux you'll want to call those service methods in the .subscribe() method after buffering enough elements in your Sinks.Many.

Comment: the issue is that I need to return a Mono, your code returns a flux..

Comment: You need collect all the individual `Mono<Map>` objects into a `Mono<List<Map>>`. You can do by using `.collectList()` operation on each Flux. Then, you can transform the list of results into a single `AggregateResult` object.

Comment: not clear how..

Comment: can you give more details?